# CSS if an element hover than element active change

Tags: css, if-statement, variables

It's possible to achieve this in any way?
If the btn "home" on state :active is red and visible, when I move the mouse :hover on another btn "about" it's possible to change the opacity of "home" :active and make it disappear?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! You have to add a [mcve] to your question to show your actual code and what you've tried. Please edit your question, click `<>` button to add your code snippet.

Answer (score -2):

add class home to the active and class about to the not active

```
  $(document).ready(function () {    
   $(".home").mouseover(function () {
    $(".about").addClass("active");
    $(".home").removeClass("active");
   });
   $(".about").mouseover(function () {
    $(".home").addClass("active");
    $(".about").removeClass("active");
   });
   });
```